# Cannot install any package in R

Tags: r, package

I am using Windows, and am unable to install any package in R. I tried it with R 3.53 and 3.62. Both give an error.
I get the following type of error in the end:

```
Error in install.packages : cannot open file 'C:/Users/Arti Agarwal/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/file3a2065f64427/BH/include/boost/geometry/util/readme.txt': Permission denied
```

I also get this type of an error in between:

```
  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
     binary source needs_compilation
yaml  2.2.0  2.2.1              TRUE
```

I don't know how to troubleshoot this further. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you perhaps on a corporate environment and using a computer on which you have restricted user rights?

Comment: I have had problems in years past (on windows) with having R installed in a path containing spaces; while I did not test it on the library path as well, it is feasible. I think it's more likely to be either corporate network policy (as @user100487 said) or an antivirus thing (windows defender fw/av has recently slowed down some of my R processes with its anti-malware engine).

Comment: Are you able to create that directory path and an empty file without error? If so, consider https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028485/windows-10-add-an-exclusion-to-windows-security for a folder exception or a program exception.

Comment: I think it might be an antivirus thing, since I am not on a corporate network or pc. I will check how this can be avoided & reply. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I added an exception in the antivirus. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed it. Posting the answer for the benefit for anyone else having the same problem.

1) I fixed the file permission error by running R as admin.
2) The packages don't work with R 3.6.2 or R 3.5.3 but strangely enough they work with R 3.6.1
It gives a warning that the package was built with R 3.6.2 but it doesnt work with it when you install it. Hence the confusion.

thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score -3):

Install conda for windows

```
# if you have 64 bit computer:
https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe
# if 32 bit computer:
https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Windows-x86.exe
```

Run the exe.
Create a new environment for your R:

```
# create new virtual environment for R with name 'newR'
conda create --name newR
# enter this created environment
conda activate newR # or: source activate newR
# install there now newest R
conda install -c conda-forge r-base
# you can also install rstudio
conda install -c conda-forge rstudio
# and also more difficult to install R packages
# search for them by googling: 'conda install <packagename>'
# mostly in anaconda site you see command for install.


# next time you want to start R do:

# enter environment
conda activate newR # if that doesn't work: source activate newR
# start R
R
```

Learn basic conda commands investing only 11 minutes:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YJC6ldI3hWk

If you want to become a serious developer/programmer - sooner or later anyway you have to learn conda.

Comment: This suggestion feels like an unnecessary complication (and the number of questions on SO on difficulties installing r packages in the conda env  could suggest the suggestion is not a change for the better) . Given that the issue in the OP may be a permissions issue installing further software is unlikely to help.

Comment: @user20650 there might be various problems why the user cannot install R into his computer. Conda is exactly for such problematic cases. He can either spend further hours to try to clear his problem. Or just spend few minutes to install conda and run `conda install -c conda-forge r-base`. - Did you ever used conda? As a developer he has to learn to solve his problems in the most practical way. - Sooner or later you have to use conda - because of dependency hell.

Comment: I cant see why `install.packages` should not be the recommended approach as default. Id recommend sorting out these issues there before the additions of further software.

Comment: I use R for several years. Sometimes install.packages() won't do the job although it should. it is the case, when the package or one of the packages you want to install is depending on some non-R library or binary - not installed or installed but with wrong version.

Comment: His binary version error message concerning `yaml` smells like that.

Comment: java dependency regularly creates problems which i couldn't solve without conda. Sooner or later as an R developer one has to use conda. Because there will be packages not compatible with certain versions of R but with others. - `curl` is e.g. a dependency regularly creating issues.

Comment: Plus it seems the questioner doesn't have admin rights in his windows computer. Conda installs things and all the dependencies locally. Installing conda doesn't require admin rights and installing packages using conda neither. I didn't recommend him just blindly conda. I am using conda to install stuff in clusters where I don't have admin rights. It is the only way to manage dependencies without loosing hours/days (well still you loose sometimes hours and days - but without conda how much days it will be then?) - without admin rights on a device.

Comment: I don't agree with the advice that "*Sooner or later as an R developer one **has to use conda***"; but i agree with you that we should use the tools that best work for us.

Comment: You do, because R updates its versions every half year. And in newer versions of packages (they frequently change function names in packages!) - your code from 1 year ago won't work any more. So you have to install several different versions of R on your computer and conserve the packages for each of the versions. Without keeping the different versions of R running older code will be impossible. Conda saves you tons of time in that procedure. - For me - I wouldn't know how I should manage all the packages and versions without conda. I create for every R version a new conda environment.

Comment: Although i disagree with you @Gwang-JinKim, there are certain benefits to using `conda`, as you stated. Most of these seems centered around enterprise usage (such as restricted rights) or lack of understanding outside the language (such as environment variables on windows, obtaining the correct bit-version [java32 vs java 64] etc.). Having multi-version support and back-compatibility is indeed a good argument for `conda` or similar environment services, but for day-to-day use, it might be more beneficial to try and understand the root-of-the-problem instead of relying on 3-party software. :-)